# adding a dictionary to nested dict python

Tags: python, dictionary

i have 3 nodes and 3 colors (R, G, B) and im trying to create a dictionary with all possible combinations of nodes and colors (so its 3^3 = 27 possible combinations)
which is supposed to look like

```
{0:  {0: 'R', 1: 'R', 2: 'R'}, 1: {0: 'R', 1: 'R', 2: 'G'}, 3: etc
```

but my dictionary colorized_nodes just keeps updating and in the end I end up with only the last combination left. I can't understand what is wrong with it.
my code looks like that:

```
import itertools

colorized_nodes=dict()
colorized=dict()

nodes = [1, 2, 3] 
colors = ['R','G','B'] 
nodes_count=len(nodes)
colors_count=len(colors)
all_combs=nodes_count**colors_count

#all possible combinations of colors
comb=itertools.product(colors, repeat=colors_count)
allcombs=list(comb)


for i in range (all_combs):
    for index,color in enumerate(allcombs[i]):
        colorized[index]=color
    colorized_nodes={**colorized_nodes, **colorized}
    print(colorized_nodes)
    colorized={}

print('checkpoint') 
print(colorized_nodes)
```

Comment: Dicts have unique keys and you are trying to add each time to the same keys: the numbers from `numbers`. Change to `colorized_nodes[i] = dict(colorized)`

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code always uses only one key to store stuff - you can streamline your code a bit by using `enumerate` throughout:

```
#all possible combinations of colors
comb=itertools.product(colors, repeat=colors_count)
allcombs=list(comb)

# see below for loop-equivalent
cols = {i:{ii:vv for ii,vv in enumerate(v)} for i,v in enumerate(allcombs)}
print(cols)
```

Output:

```
{0: {0: 'R', 1: 'R', 2: 'R'}, 1: {0: 'R', 1: 'R', 2: 'G'}, 2: {0: 'R', 1: 'R', 2: 'B'},
 3: {0: 'R', 1: 'G', 2: 'R'}, 4: {0: 'R', 1: 'G', 2: 'G'}, 5: {0: 'R', 1: 'G', 2: 'B'}, 
 6: {0: 'R', 1: 'B', 2: 'R'}, 7: {0: 'R', 1: 'B', 2: 'G'}, 8: {0: 'R', 1: 'B', 2: 'B'}, 
 9: {0: 'G', 1: 'R', 2: 'R'},10: {0: 'G', 1: 'R', 2: 'G'},11: {0: 'G', 1: 'R', 2: 'B'}, 
 12: {0: 'G', 1: 'G', 2: 'R'},13: {0: 'G', 1: 'G', 2: 'G'},14: {0: 'G', 1: 'G', 2: 'B'}, 
 15: {0: 'G', 1: 'B', 2: 'R'},16: {0: 'G', 1: 'B', 2: 'G'},17: {0: 'G', 1: 'B', 2: 'B'}, 
 18: {0: 'B', 1: 'R', 2: 'R'},19: {0: 'B', 1: 'R', 2: 'G'},20: {0: 'B', 1: 'R', 2: 'B'}, 
 21: {0: 'B', 1: 'G', 2: 'R'},22: {0: 'B', 1: 'G', 2: 'G'},23: {0: 'B', 1: 'G', 2: 'B'}, 
 24: {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'R'},25: {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'G'},26: {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'B'}}
```

The dict comprehension is equivalent to

```
for idx,part in enumerate(allcombs):
    colorized={}
    for index, color in enumerate(part):
        colorized[index]=color
    colorized_nodes[idx]=colorized
```